# React native button onpress show 2 new buttons and make other stuff unclickable

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want after press on the FloatingButton, to show 2 more buttons.
While I have these 2 buttons shown, I want to make the rest of this page to be uncklickable,
that the user has to press one of these to go on navigating.
This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import FloatingButton from '../components/FloatingButton';

    const DuellScreen = () => {
    
        return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.container2}>
                <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>body</Text>
             </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                 <FloatingButton/>
            </View>
         </View>
        )
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            padding: 16,
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            alignItems: 'center'
        },
        container2: {
            padding: 16,
            flex: 5,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
        },
    });
    
    
    export default DuellScreen
```

How can I do this, especially the 2 button visible after buttonpress + make the other things unclickable?

Comment: define 'unclickable'? I assume you only have onPress events on your FloatingButton and the other 2 buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import FloatingButton from '../components/FloatingButton';

const DuellScreen = (props) => {

    const [active, setActive] = useState(true);
    
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.container2}>
                <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>body</Text>
            </ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FloatingButton onPress={active ? () => setActive(false) : () => {} } />

                {!active ? 
                    <View>
                        <FloatingButton onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('OtherScreen')} />
                        <FloatingButton onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('AnotherScreen')} />
                    </View>    
                : null}
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```